# Python/Pandas: apply my own rule to a column and put it in a specific position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I have a table with 10+ columns. Let's say that the column_1 is a name and if the name ends in letter 'a' I want to create a rule which would fill my new column to 'Female'. In other cases it would be 'Male'.
I want this new column to be right after column1 so I get something like:

df1:

1. Adam Male (other coulmns)
2. Elena Female (other coulmns)
3. Jack Male (other coulmns)
4. Jessica Female (other coulmns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(1, 'Name', np.where(df['col1'].str.endswith('a'), 'Female', 'Male'))
```

Or, if you don't know the position of 'col1':

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc('col1')+1
df.insert(pos, 'Name', np.where(df['col1'].str.endswith('a'), 'Female', 'Male'))
```

output:

```
      col1    Name  col2
0     Adam    Male     0
1    Elena  Female     1
2     Jack    Male     2
3  Jessica  Female     3
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Adam', 'Elena', 'Jack', 'Jessica'], 'col2': range(4)})
```